# Power Bi subtracting from different table on row level

Tags: powerbi

So I got few excel files that I imported into Power BI 
For simplicity I used two files

both files has Name , grade Level, mentor, date of join
The only difference between the files is that File A is at the start of 2017 and File B is at the end of the same year.

I have joined the tables on Name

however I am interested on Grade Level (i.e. progression from start of year to the end of the year )

File A (start of the year)

```
NAME:       GRADE LEVEL:     MENTOR:      DATE OF JOIN
"BECKHAM" , "A1,"            "FERGUSON,"  "2017"
```

File B (end of the year)

```
NAME:       GRADE LEVEL:     MENTOR:      DATE OF JOIN
"Beckham"   "A2"             "Ferguson"   "2017"
```

Note- this is simple version of the data-

What I like to do- assign numerical value to A1 and so on for example
    A1=1 A2 = 2 A3=3... upto A9=9

Objectives:
See the progression levels of Mentor Ferguson (the growth from A1 to A2)

Comment: This is still a bit Broad. What is the expected outcome.

Comment: So - grade level A1  (are the start of junior members )
in this example - i want to see progression from start to end of the year.
The only measurement of progression is Grade Level....
   Thus- i like to summarise Mentor Ferguson at the end of the year with a point system

Comment: Edit your post and for an input what is the expected output.